# JQuery won´t fire, if php function has more than 5 arguments

Tags: php, jquery, function, arguments

i know it sounds weired :)

I´m creating a selfmade Dropdown with a php function:

```
function createDropDown($a,$b,$c,$d){        
/* Somethin without Varialbes for test (it also appears)*/
}
```

Call of the function:

```
createDropDown($ARRDisplayValue,'Location1','Choose',0);
```

My JQuery to expand the dropdown:

```
$('body').on('click','.Drp-Select-Lable',function(){
        $(this).parent().children('.Drp-OptionGroup').show();
    });
```

It work all perfect, dropdown expand and so on.
But if i add an extra argument to the php function Jquery wont work anymore..?

like that:

```
 function createDropDown($a,$b,$c,$d,$VARIALBEFAULT){        
/* Somethin without Varialbes for test (it also appears)*/
}
createDropDown($ARRDisplayValue,'Location1','Choose',0,'SomeValue');
```

If i do that, Jquery won´t fire?!

Please help, thanks!

Full function code:

```
function createDropDown($ARRDisplayValue,$TXTInputName,$TXTInputCaption,$DECInputWith){        
if($DECInputWith==0){$DECInputWith = 100;}


echo '<div class="Drp-Select" style="width:'.$DECInputWith.'px">
        <div class="Drp-Select-Lable" id="FID_'.$TXTInputName.'" data-value="'.$TXTInputCaption.'" style="background: url(APP/CAL/SPT/DownPointer.png) no-repeat scroll calc('.$DECInputWith.'px ) 5px;">'.$TXTInputCaption.'</div>
        <div class="Drp-OptionGroup">';
        for($i=0; $i<count($ARRDisplayValue)-1; $i++){    
            echo '<div class="Drp-Select-Option" data-value="'.$ARRDisplayValue[$i].'" value="'.$ARRDisplayValue[$i].'">
                <div class=".Drp-Select-Option-Opt">'.$ARRDisplayValue[$i].'</div>
            </div>';
            }
echo '  </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="FHPUT_'.$TXTInputName.'" value="">
    </div>';}
```

Full call code:

```
$ARRDisplayValue = array('Halle 1','Halle 2','Halle 3','Externe Prüfung');
createDropDown($ARRDisplayValue,'Location1','Halle wählen',0) ;
```

Comment: May be your `createDropDown` function breaks when you add the last argument?

Comment: Instead of passing number of arguments, pass an array as an argument. Then you can add as much value as you want and your function will never raise an issue regarding extra parameter at least

Comment: variables that i use real are arrays (simplified for post, but the problem also appears)

Comment: You can not over-write function input structure until you use the child-parent class concept

Comment: it also appears on any position, not only the last argument

Comment: @AlivetoDie what do you mean with the child-parent concept? Arguments in PHP affects query?

Comment: Can you show us what the code that generates the dropdown `.Drp-Select-Lable`

Comment: @CesarBielich i added it to post

Comment: Show me what it looks like with the 5th argument added to the function

Comment: @CesarBielich i only add the argument to the call and to the function. Nothing really special going on. I´m not going to use the passed variable (for tests)

Comment: Im not sure how your list is hidden in the first place to be shown from the jquery. You need to change your code from this `<div class="Drp-OptionGroup">` to this `<div class="Drp-OptionGroup" style="display: none">`. That would initially hide the dropdown and on click will then show it. I tried it on a box of mine and it seems to work fine for me as long as you add that.

Comment: @CesarBielich its hidden in stylesheet: .Drp-OptionGroup ,  .Drp-MultipleOptionGroup{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 10px 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

Comment: I duplicated it on my own box with the 5th variable and it works for me. There must be something else.

Comment: @CesarBielich thanks for trying, i know its strange. i have a other function, that uses the same jquery and classes with more than 5 arguments

Comment: @CesarBielich jquery version? i use the latest online